# Transpile for await...of toES5

Tags: node.js, babeljs, ecmascript-5

I am trying to transpile an npm module created by someone(the license allows code editing) using babel, but it throws SyntaxError if the code has `{ ...myObject }` and `for await (i of iteravle)`, so how can I transpile `for await...of` to ES5-compatible manually?

Comment: Why do you need to manually transpile it if you're using Babel?

Comment: Because my installed babel(I installed today and didn't specify the version so it should be the latest version) cannot transpile / does not recognize the `for await (i of iterable)` statement so it throws a SyntaxError and does not transpile

Comment: Please give a [mre] showing what you're running and how it's configured. Or just use https://babeljs.io/repl